# why does replaceAll throw an exception

Tags: java, regex

i have a string where i want to get rid of brackets

this is my string `"(name)"`
and i want to get `"name"`

the same thing without the brackets

i had `String s = "(name)";`

i wrote

```
s = s.replaceAll("(","");
s = s.replaceAll(")","");
```

and i get an exception for that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 1
(
```

how do i get rid of the brackets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parenthesis characters `(` and `)` delimit the bounds of a [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) in a regular expression which is used as the first argument in [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). The characters need to be escaped.

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\(","");
s = s.replaceAll("\\)","");
```

Better yet, you could simply place the parenthesis in a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) to prevent the characters being interpreted as meta-characters

```
s = s.replaceAll("[()]","");
```

Comment: strangely enough i clicked about 10 times on this answer before it let me accept it..

Comment: Its necessary to wait at least 15 mins to accept an answer on `SO`

Comment: that is odd.. why is that?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85521/why-does-stackoverflow-make-you-wait-2-x-minutes-before-you-can-accept-an-answer) has the answer...

Comment: I wrote an answer in a different thread comparing `replaceAll` and `replace` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047372/245966 **Note that in many cases you probably want to use `replace` which is much simpler to use than `replaceAll`.** Note also than unlike in JavaScript, in Java `replace` replaces all occurrences, not only the first one!

Answer (score 4):

`s = s.replace("(", "").replace(")", "");`

Regex isn't needed here.

If you wanted to use Regex (not sure why you would) you could do something like this:

`s = s.replaceAll("\\(", "").replaceAll("\\)", "");`

The problem was that `(` and `)` are meta characters so you need to escape them (assuming you want them to be interpreted as how they appear).

Answer (score 3):

[String#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll) takes regular expression as argument.
You are using `Grouping Meta-characters` as regular expression argument.That is why getting error.

> Meta-characters are used to group, divide, and perform special operations in patterns.

```
\       Escape the next meta-character (it becomes a normal/literal character)
^       Match the beginning of the line
.       Match any character (except newline)
$       Match the end of the line (or before newline at the end)
|       Alternation (‘or’ statement)
()      Grouping
[]      Custom character class
```

So use
1.`\\(` instead of `(`
2. `\\)` instead of  `)`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to escape the brackets like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\(","");
s = s.replaceAll("\\)","");
```

You need two slashes since the regex processing engine would need to see a `\(` to process the bracket as a literal bracket (and not as part of the regex expression), and you'll need to escape the backslash so the regex engine would be able to see it as a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the ( and the ) they have special string literal meaning. 
Do it like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\(","");
s = s.replaceAll("\\)","");
```

Comment: It does not modify itself, it creates a new `String`.

Comment: does it? let me check.

Comment: Oh it does sorry my bad i didn't realise.

Answer (score 1):

```
s=s.replace("(","").replace(")","");
```