# android - java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using replaceAll on a specific string containing special characters

Tags: java, android, replace, replaceall

### PROBLEM

I'm using Abatis as ORM. When I try to insert a json containing a specific string it crashes.

I have extracted the code from Abatis that generates the error:

### CODE

```
            Map<String, Object> bindParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            bindParams.put("id", "194fa0f2-9706-493f-97ab-4eb300a8e4ed");
            bindParams.put("field", "{\"Messages\":\"ERRORE durante l'invocazione del servizio. 01 - Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@18a96588] did not accept task: org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1@14a7c67b\",\"Errors\":1}");

            String sql = "UPDATE <TABLE> SET NoteAgente = #field# WHERE Id = #id#";

            if (bindParams != null) {
                Iterator<String> mapIterator = bindParams.keySet().iterator();
                while (mapIterator.hasNext()) {
                    String key = mapIterator.next();
                    Object value = bindParams.get(key);

                    if(value instanceof String && value != null)
                        value = value.toString().replace("'", "''");

                    sql = sql.replaceAll("#" + key + "#", value == null ? "null"
                            : "'" + value.toString() + "'");
                }
            }
```

The problem is in the **replaceAll** method with the string **$1@14a7c67b**. You can also debug it writing

```
String s = "onetwothree";               
s = s.replaceAll("one", "$1@14a7c67b");
```

and it will also crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression argument, and `$1` is a special way of telling the java regex engine to use group-one as the replacement.

You need to use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) which matches/replaces the string literally:

```
String s = "onetwothree";
s = s.replace("one", "$1@14a7c67b");
```

You could also escape the `$` character if you still need to use `replaceAll`:

```
s = s.replaceAll("one", "\\$1@14a7c67b");
```

Comment: Perfect answer! It works like a charm! Can't just mark this as answer, I will do it as soon as I can.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047372/245966 ;  note also that unlike in JavaScript, in Java `replace` replaces all occurrences, not only the first one!